# How to Deserialize specific JSON string

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I've been trying to deserialize a specific JSON string using the JavaScriptSerializer class for a day now without success.
I've read a fair few posts on here, but cant find one that addresses a JSON string similar in design to the one I need to use, so I'm asking my own.

The string I need to deserialize is as follows:

```
["SomeName",[["alpha","bravo"],[1,6]],[["John","Bob","Paul","Ringo"],[1,2,1,8]]]
```

I *thought* this class would solve it, but I was evidently wrong:

```
[Serializable]
internal class OuterDeserializedObj
{
    [Serializable]
    internal class InnerDeserializedObj
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Array1 { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Array2 { get; set; }
    }

    public List<InnerDeserializedObj> innerObj { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you post the whole JSON? seems that JSON isn't valid.

Comment: I've now added a complete JSON copy+paste from the provider

Comment: The author of that JSON string must have been really drunk

Comment: The problem with your class is that Name is not a property of the elements in the object, but rather, the first element of the array (you are receiving an array/list where the first element is a string, and the rest of elements are a list of lists of strings). I would like to help you more, but I'm not sure how would I parse that with JavaScriptSerializer...

Comment: I totally agree with jgauffin :P

Comment: If I could get it changed, I certainly would.. If I knew what they were drinking, I certainly would try it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json is just an array (array of array of array of objects), Therefore the only way i can think of is to create a similar structure in c#.

(Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/))

```
string json = @"[""SomeName"",[[""alpha"",""bravo""],[1,6]],[[""John"",""Bob"",""Paul"",""Ringo""],[1,2,1,8]]]";
var arr = JArray.Parse(json);

string name = (string)arr.OfType<JValue>().First();
var arrays = arr.OfType<JArray>()
                .Select(x => x.Select(y=>y.Select(z=>(string)z)
                                           .ToList())
                               .ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This does work perfectly, but like you say, needs to use Json.Net. I'm hoping to not have to add this as a requirement, but if no-one can solve it without, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks